# What's the male equivalent of a lady's companion?

Tags: social-history, nobility, social-class, employment

I've been wondering if men used to have a paid attendant comparable to a lady's companion.

I've seen it being compared to a valet but valets were normally more subservient and of a lower social status than their master, often starting as footmen. It seems more like the male equivalent of a handsmaiden.

Was there any position filled by a man comparable to a lady's companion in the following aspects?

1. Paid (even if in a symbolic amount).
2. Acts more like a friend to his master rather than a servant but is still subservient in a way.
3. Has the same social status as the employer or just slightly below him.
4. Primarily expected to simply provide company and conversation to his employer, play cards with him, hunt with him, etc.

I understand that the need for such an attendant would not be the same because upper-class men were not as confined to their homes as upper-class women, nor did they need a chaperone for going out in public but given the homosocial element of many historical cultures, it would make sense to have a peer in such a role.

My question was closed for being too vague so I'll try to narrow it down. Since the lady's companion is in itself a more eurocentric term, I suppose I'm mostly looking for early modern to 19th century European suggestions.

Comment: You've given a potential timespan but what about culture? I imagine that the situation in central Europe would be different to the Middle East or East Asia.

Comment: No idea how accurate this is, but I remember reading that part of Charles Darwin's role on the Beagle was to be a companion of appropriate social rank to the ship's captain

Comment: @JayFor You're correct, Darwin was on the Beagle's 2nd voyage as a companion to Captain FitzRoy.

Comment: You mean like the (fictional) relationship between Sherlock Holmes and Watson? Or Sam and Frodo?

Comment: Kings had their *favorites*, sometimes simply as friends/companions and sometimes as lovers (like the Duke of Backingham, or the favorites of Henry III of France).

Comment: I think this should be reopened. It seems clear to me, although admittedly hard to answer.

Comment: One answer might be covered by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicerone in the context of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour .  If the young gentlemen on tour were young, their family would send a tutor to accompany them.

Comment: I wonder if the *companion* job wasn't also, at least sometimes, a less-obvious *chaperone* job.  That would of depend on many things, not least who paid the wages for the companion.  I *don't* know if that was generally the case.  But if it was, then there would be no need for a male equivalent.

Comment: Penurious old school chum?